# Sitefinity upgrade 8.2 to 13

Tags: upgrade, sitefinity, sitefinity-13

Hi Im trying to upgrade sitefinity website from 8.2 to 13.1 
After i done the upgrade through the Sitefinity CMS Project Manager im receiving below error by trying to build the project 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not precompile the file 'MVC\Views\AccountActivation\AccountActivation.AccountActivation.cshtml'. Ensure that a generator declaration exists in the cshtml file.
A generator declaration is the first line of your cshtml file and looks like this:
@* Generator: MvcHelper *@
Valid host names: MvcHelper, MvcView, Template, WebPagesHelper, WebPage, RazorGenerator.Core.IHostProvider  SitefinityWebApp

Can anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a custom resource package under ResourcePackages folder.

If that's the case, probably the **razorgenerator.directives** file is missing in your package folder.

Per this KB: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Could-not-precompile-the-file-error-on-build-after-Feather-upgrade

> Copy the razorgenerator.directives file from the Bootstrap package and
> paste it in your resource package root folder, for instance
> \ResourcePackages\MyPackage

In your case the Bootstrap package is probably missing, so get it from **Bootstrap4** package.